# Custom Test Plans for Android VTS

Tags: android, android-vts

Is there a way to create custom test plans for Android VTS? This website https://android.googlesource.com/platform/test/vts/+/refs/heads/android10-dev/tools/vts-tradefed/res/config/plans.md talks about default tests, but what I would like to achieve is to create a completely new (custom) VTS plan that for new modules we added to the standard AOSP.